# What model to use with repeated measures of count data and a between subjects factor?

Tags: repeated-measures, glmm, count-data

my design is pretty simple. I have two groups (control and clinical) that play a computerized ball-tossing game in which they are excluded at varying rates by 2 computer players. There are 5 different conditions relating to the rates of exclusion and these are administered in a randomized fashion. I have count data representing players behavioral response, i.e. tossing to excluding player, and would like to see the main effects of group and condition as well as their interaction effect on this behavioral response variable. Would a GLMM be the best way to proceed? Appreciate any guidance, thank you!

[image: screenshot of a sample from my dataset. Coax is the behavioral response variable and represents the count for that behavior. The total number of trials can vary quite a bit across conditions.]

Comment: Sounds like an appropriate way to proceed to me.

Comment: Thank you @JeremyMiles! I've haven't used GLMM before so would like to be sure before continuing. Based on some reading, it seems I should use a binomial distribution and log link function? Also, I am was not sure about what the random effect would be, as every participant undergoes the same treatment, any thoughts?

Comment: Participants are random. Sounds Poisson to me though, not binomial (outcomes are counts)? Perhaps post some data.

Comment: @JeremyMiles added a screenshot to my original post. "Coax" is the behavioral response variable and represents the count for that behavior out of the total number of responses (which you can see vary quite a bit across conditions)

Comment: Hmmm.. can you use an offset with Poisson regression in GLMM in your software?

Comment: @JeremyMiles I'm using SPSS which can be quite limiting, but I believe I can select a Poisson distribution (specifying a link function) and there is an option for "weights and offsets" 
Is that what you mean?

Comment: Not sure. I don't use SPSS. It certainly sounds like it.

Comment: @JeremyMiles so I would add the total responses in the offset field to account for the variability in the response rate? Thanks so much again for you help!

Comment: I believe so, yes. But I've never done a Glmm with poison outcome and an offset (and not in spss).